# How to provide a way to edit a text on my flask application from front end?

Tags: python, html, mysql, authentication, flask

I'm creating a flask app, I want to provide a way to edit the text on my personal website once I have logged in. I'm currently using MySQL as my database. To be clear I want the editing do be done from front end, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WTForm](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#creating-forms) in flask, pass that edited data to the database on form submit.

Flask-WTF provides your Flask application integration with WTForms. For example:
`
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

`

Note
From version 0.9.0, Flask-WTF will not import anything from wtforms, you need to import fields from wtforms.

In addition, a CSRF token hidden field is created automatically. You can render this in your template:
`

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

`If your form has multiple hidden fields, you can render them in one block using hidden_tag().`

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

`Validating Forms Validating the request in your view handlers:`

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #you can write your db logic here.
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

`
Note that you don't have to pass request.form to Flask-WTF; it will load automatically. And the convenience validate_on_submit will check if it is a POST request and if it is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you provide a small example of how it is implemented?